Configure a bitbucket runner to run continuously on macOS
I created the runner and added it to macOS and when I run the start command it works. But I would like to make it run continuously. And I saw that I have to create a config file in LaunchAgents to run continuously. I created it but it doesn't run. I ran it with the command launchctl load name_file.
With this two files I tried:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>bitbucket-pipelines-runner</string>

                <key>RunAtLoad</key>
                <true />

                <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
                <string>/Users/ciagent/atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner/bin</string>
                <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                <array>
                        <string>/bin/bash</string>
                        <string>--login</string>
                        <string>-c</string>
                        <string>./start.sh --accountUuid {...} --repositoryUuid {...} --runnerUuid {...} --OAuthClientId ... --OAuthClientSecret ... --runtime macos-bash --workingDirectory ../temp</string>
                </array>
        </dict>
</plist



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.bitbucket.runner</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/ciagent/atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner/bin/./start.sh --accountUuid {...} --repositoryUuid {...} --runnerUuid {...} --OAuthClientId ... --OAuthClientSecret ... --runtime macos-bash --workingDirectory ../temp</string>
        <string>run</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/bitbucket-runner-error.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/bitbucket-runner.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>

I don't get any output.
I looked for tutorials on this but there aren't many. Can anyone help me with this?
